# sqlite - query to find a table / database size?

Tags: sqlite

Anyone know how to get a database total filesize for sqlite? Alternatively if its only possible to get a table size I'd like to know how to get multiple tables sizes in query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A SQLite database is stored in a single file. That file's size is the size of your database.

Comment: obviously, however this is for an html5 web app where it's stored in the browser and due to the 5mb limit we have to monitor the client side database to ensure that that 5mb limit isn't reached.

Comment: @Joe: What's obvious is highly subjective. You should make it obvious in your question that you don't have direct access to the file.

Comment: Depending on [SQLite journaling mode](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) an SQLite database may take several files.